# Google Play Services How to retrieve user's saved games from another application

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to build an android application that would be an "add-on" to another application that uses google play services to save games. Is there any way for my application to access the saved game(s) (with user's permission of course) for this other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames). To retrieve all saved games for the currently signed-in player, call the `load` method. Your game can also retrieve a specific saved game through the player's UI selection, as described in [Displaying Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#displaying_saved_game). The returned saved game is represented as a [`Snapshot`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshot.html), which your game can then open to read its content and metadata.